# "TF- Advanced Email and SMS Task 2020.18.1" truncating email address when having a apostrophe sign

Tags: c#, .net, email, ssis, apostrophe

In my SSIS package, I have "TF- Advanced Email and SMS Task 2020.18.1" controller. So I have a recipient that his email address is like below

Test.T'Est@domaim.com

So when I'm sending email to above address, the "TF- Advanced Email and SMS Task 2020.18.1" controller truncate the email address before apostrophe (') and sending

So currently it is sending email to this kind of address

Est@domaim.com

So it is truncating the first part of the email address before apostrophe sign. Really appreciate, if anyone can help me on this.

----Update----
I guess some work around need to do here. What I tried is manipulating the email address before passing to "TF-Advanced Email and SMS" controller.

[This is the flow, currently I'm executing. In c# script I tied to manipulate the "To" address before sending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KE2hG.png)

Also I tried something like this

```
string ToEmail = "{Test.T'Est}"+"@testdomain.com";
ToEmail.replace('{',' ');
ToEmail.replace('}',''\');
''''

Then when I send a email through "TF-Advance Email.." controller, it will send a email to below address.

Test.T'Est'@testdomain.com

But the additional apostrophe will be there Also, **it cannot replace with current apostrophe**, like this ("Test.T{'}Est@testdomain.com" - this is not working)

So still **did not find any clue** on this.
```

Comment: Did you copy and paste that email address? Is it possible that the apostrophe only looks like one and is actually a different unicode character?

Comment: No the email address is binding dynamically from C# code from the script. So I created a parameter and in the run time the parameter will get assign the value and it will be use in "TF-Advanced Email and SMS Task". Also I tried to pass UTF-16 character code for apostrophe(') but still did not work.